# Java Azure SDK inside OSGI

Tags: java, azure, sdk, osgi

I'm working on to create OSGI bundle which wrappes Java [Azure SDK 0.9.2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java),
I manager to create bundle by resolving all dependency and bring it in Active state.  but since the the way Azure SDK modules are designed , I see it is failing while loading services with  ServiceLoader.load(Builder.Exports.class)

I tried [workarounds](http://blog.osgi.org/2013/02/javautilserviceloader-in-osgi.html) mentioned to get working ServiceLoader.load() work in OSGI env , but so far it is not working for me , now I'm getting below error.

```
Direct constraints which are unresolved:
    Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)".
    Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.serviceloader; filter="(osgi.serviceloader=com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.Builder.Exports)".
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you will need to install [Aries spi-fly](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html) into your runtime.